# Graph with uneven intervals on y axis

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I've tried without luck do make such graph in WinForms with Chart control.[Graph with uneven intervals on y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veuCl.png) My first idea was to use pointed Chart with images for empty and not empty marker. The lines are displayed, but unfortunatelly there is a big space between values 4 - 19 and 20 - 33. Is there a way to avoid the space when using standard WinForms chart Control? 
My second idea was to use a DatagridView. I could add not more that something aboit 700 columns. I would need almost 2000 columns. Thus the DataGridView isn't best choice for me.

Thank for any hint how to achieve it.

[image]

Edit 1:

As sugested by TnTinMn I've tried ScaleBreakStyle. This seems to remove some spaces from the graph. At the moment my graph looks like this:

[image]

This was achieved by the Code:

```
 var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

 chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = false;
 chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
 chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
 chartArea.AxisX.IsReversed = true;
 chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 1;
 chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
 chartArea.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;
 chartArea.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.BreakLineStyle = BreakLineStyle.None;
 chartArea.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 0;
 chartArea.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.CollapsibleSpaceThreshold = 50;
 chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

If I try to put the y labels on the left side, it doesn't work

```
chartArea.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
chartArea.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

Adding folowing code doesn't solve the problem:

```
 chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;
 chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleBreakStyle.BreakLineStyle = BreakLineStyle.None;
 chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 0;
 chartArea.AxisY2.ScaleBreakStyle.CollapsibleSpaceThreshold = 50;
 chartArea.AxisY2.Interval = 1;
```

How can I remove 26 and 28, and leave only 1 and 27 on the chart? How can I put 1 and 27 on the bottom and leave a "big" space above them?

Edit 2:

After some tryies I've achieved what I wanted(I still have to adjust the marker images, but it looks very promising).
This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

As TnTiMn said, it is a little bit tricky. I had to map 1, 2, 3... to my real values and then to assign custom labels. I didn't used ScaleBreakStyle. Thanks anyway for your help.

My code:

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chart1.Series[0].MarkerImage ="NotEmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.Series[0].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerImage = "EmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.Series[1].MarkerImage = "NotEmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.Series[1].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerImage = "EmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.Series[2].MarkerImage = "NotEmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.Series[2].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerImage = "EmptyPoint.png";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;

        int number = 0;
        string mappedNumber;

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        {
            number = 1;
            mappedNumber = "1";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i, number);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(number - 0.5, number + 0.5, mappedNumber);
            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Count - 1].IsEmpty = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        {
            number = 2;
            mappedNumber = "7";
            chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(i, number);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(number - 0.5, number + 0.5, mappedNumber);

            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series2"].Points[chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.Count - 1].IsEmpty = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        {
            number = 3;
            mappedNumber = "20";
            chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(i, number);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(number - 0.5, number + 0.5, mappedNumber);

            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series3"].Points[chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.Count - 1].IsEmpty = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the markers all sit on the lines. What are the y-values? Also: I see no 'big space' at the intervals you mention.

Comment: Have you investigated setting `chart1.ChartAreas("Default").AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = True` and the associated properties?  see [AxisScaleBreakStyle Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscalebreakstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TaW - points are just values from some calculation. It doesn't metter for me if it is string or int, at the moment if it helps. @ TnTinMn - Yes, I've tried ScaleBreakStyle. This seems to be the right solution. However I still have some problems(see my updated post)

Comment: You have a very strict criteria for what you want displayed and I seriously doubt that you will get that result without a lot of coding effort; i.e. the automatic axis formatting is not designed for your task.  One possible solution is to plot each series in its own ChartArea and you would need to control the positioning and probably the axis labeling.  Not impossible, but it would be a significant effort.